# Xamarin android: resource id/button_img_del (aka com.companyname.www:id/button_img_del) not found.?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Resource.Id.button_img_del cannot be found.

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="300px"
    android:layout_height="400px">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">
            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img_item"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <ProgressBar
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1" />
                
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@id/button_img_del"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_mtrl_chip_close_circle">

            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Error:

> failed linking file resources.             resource id/button_img_del (aka
> com.companyname.www:id/button_img_del) not found.

My C# code for RecyclerView.Adapter :

```
public class ImgViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            public ProgressBar ProgressBar { get; private set; }

            public ImgViewHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
            {
                ProgressBar = itemView.FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar1);
            }
        }
```

Solution?

Comment: Can you show this code to find button_img_del

Comment: @hungcuiga1 shared now.

Comment: oh i don't know about c#. But the code you are showing is looking for `ProgressBar`. Does it have an error? Did you have a line of code like java type `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`?

Comment: @hungcuiga1 `SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_imgInfo);`

Comment: @hknhkn Do you have this problem on progressBar1? Do you mean that you have problem on `itemView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.button_img_del)`? I can not find any problem from your code. but you can take a look [RecyclerView Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/layouts/recycler-view/recyclerview-example) firstly.

Comment: @Cherry Bu - MSFT  No, only Resource.Id.button_img_del.
But my problem is solved :)

Comment: @hknhkn Glad to hear that you solved your problem.